# Projection of ball. find initial velocity

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity, projectile, distance

A cannonball is fired at an angle of 33 degree relative to the horizontal as shown in the figure bellow.
It is 1930 meters in the horizontal direction from the point of launch to the point where the bullet lands.
The bullet is in the air for 16.8 seconds. We disregard air resistance.

[image]

i) Determine the velocity of the bullet initial speed, v0 at the point of launch.
ii) Find the vertical height difference h between the launch point and the landing point.

Answer (score 1):

This is a ballistic problem. So start from the equations for ballistic

$$x=x_{0}+v_{0x}t$$

$$y=y_{0}+v_{0y}t-\frac{1}{2}gt^{2}$$

and write them for your particular problem. Also, apply them to the final moment when the ball hits the floor. You will find this:

$$d=v_{0}\cos\left(\theta\right)t_{f}$$
$$0=h+v_{0}\sin\left(\theta\right)t_{f}-\frac{1}{2}gt_{f}^{2}$$

where $d = 1930$ m, $\theta = 33^\circ$ and $t_f = 16.8$ s. From the first equation you find

$$v_{0}=\frac{d}{t_{f}\cos\left(\theta\right)}$$

After finding $v_0$, use the second equation and find $h$:

$$h=\frac{1}{2}gt_{f}^{2}-v_{0}\sin\left(\theta\right)t_{f}$$

Answer (score 0):

i) Determine the velocity of the bullet v0 at the point of launch.

ii) Find the vertical height difference h between the launch point and the landing point.